# How to remove "public/index.php" in laravel 5.4 project for both local and shared hosting server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, plesk

Here is what i got, i tried putting .htaccess on root with following code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And on public folder .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This is error i'm having on localhost :
[image: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found on localhost]

And this is the error i'm having on shared hosting server :
[image: Plesk Server Shared Hosting error]

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0"
    }
```

No success yet. Please help i couldn't sleep

Comment: Is it "public/index.html" or "public/index.php"?

Comment: You do not need to change .htaccess file. In your localhost, open the app at "localhost/coin_app/public/index.php"

Comment: i corrected "index.php" and on local i use php artisan serve command to run its working fine but when using xampp it shows error

Comment: Which link are you using in xampp?

Comment: localhost/coin_app

Comment: Try using this link: localhost/coin_app/public/index.php

Comment: localhost/coin_app/public/index.php it's working with this but still no resolution on this -> localhost/coin_app. Also please tell me if my .htaccess is incorrect

Comment: If you want to start the app with localhost/coin_app in xampp, then you need to create virtual host in xampp.

Comment: okay let me setup virtual host and revert back to you but what should i do on shared hosting server..i don't have permission to access the panel...i'm uploading my project via FileZilla ftp

Comment: in shared hosting, you need to upload everything except public folder into the app folder. the content of public folder will go into public_html folder. then edit index.php. this will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4&t=0s&index=13&list=PLillGF-RfqbYhQsN5WMXy6VsDMKGadrJ-

Comment: on plesk hosting server "httpdocs/" is the root directory like "public_html" in other hosting server all i have is access of httpdocs/ where all the other projects are loaded.

Comment: Okay i made it work perfectly on localhost by changing the directory structure All code into "code" folder except public folder and all the content of public to root folder. and it's working on localhost url "http://localhost/coin_app/" after that to clear config cache "php artisan config:cache" command into the "code" folder now i'm uploading these changes to server.

Comment: Good job....!!!

Comment: After uploading to server it says "Server Error in '/' Application." with Runtime Error. Is there any way we can set customError like "<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>" for laravel as well ??

Comment: Shoot i have to degrade the application version to work as i found Plek server using php version 5.4 and laravel 4.2 supports that so i guess that's the only way. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166339/discussion-between-vipertecpro-and-ahsan).

Answer (score 0):

Alright i resolved my own problem

1. I followed other's suggestion by changing the folder structure plus matching the version of php on both server and which laravel supports, so in my case my server was running on php 5.4 and i was using Laravel 5.4 so i downgraded it with 4.2.
2. Plesk for Windows uses the IIS HTTP Server (http://www.iis.net/) for hosting and managing websites. So i configured in my **"web.config"** file (if it's not available create one on root ) to make it all work

   ```
   <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
           <defaultDocument>
               <files>
                   <clear />
                   <add value="index.php" />
                   <add value="default.aspx" />
                   <add value="Default.htm" />
                   <add value="Default.asp" />
                   <add value="index.htm" />
                   <add value="index.html" />
               </files>
           </defaultDocument>
           <rewrite>
               <rules>
                   <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                       <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                       <conditions>
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                       </conditions>
                       <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
                   </rule>
                   <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                       <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                       <conditions>
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                       </conditions>
                       <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                   </rule>
               </rules>
           </rewrite>
           <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
       </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
   ```

   index.php

   ```
   require __DIR__.'/your_root_folder_name/bootstrap/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/your_root_folder_name/bootstrap/start.php';
   $app->run();
   ```

   .htaccess

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
           Options -MultiViews
       </IfModule>

       RewriteEngine On

       # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
       RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

       # Handle Front Controller...
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   ```